# MStest aborts test cleanup

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mstest

I'm running my tests locally using mstest.
I use "testsettings" file in order to specify 30 minutes test timeout.

The issue is that when a test is aborted with timeout, the test cleanup is given a very short amount of time to execute, which is not enough for my cleanup to finish.

How can I increase the test cleanup timeout?

Just to be clear, I use [TestCleanup] attribute which does cleanup per test.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that is just the way it works that the cleanup time is included in the test run time for timeout purposes.  From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243175.aspx):

> **How Cleanup Methods Affect Test Run Time-Outs**
>
> A test run can include an AssemblyCleanupAttribute method and a
>   ClassCleanupAttribute method. After these methods complete, the test
>   run ends.
>
> The test run might have a time-out value assigned. The amount of time
>   that is used by the cleanup methods is added to the total amount of
>   time that is used by the test run. In other words, the cleanup time
>   counts toward the time limit that you have imposed on the test run as
>   a whole, and therefore could cause the test run to time out.